# React: Retrieve dynamic child key upon event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am aware that [dynamic children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) of a component must have a unique `key` as the following (modified example from official docs):

```js
render: function() {
  var results = this.props.results;
  return (
    {results.map(function(result) {
      return <ChildComponent type="text" key={result.id} changeCallback={this.props.callbackFn}/>;
    })}
  );
}
```

Considering that `ChildComponent` is another React component nested here, with a `render` method as bellow

```js
render: function() {
  var results = this.props.results;
  return (
    <div className="something">
       <input type="text" onChange={this.props.changeCallback} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

is there any way to access the key when `callbackFn(event)` is called?

Comment: Maybe it would help to add the same data as an id `id={result.id}`? This could easily be accessed by `event.target.id`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Although the first answer is correct this is considered as a bad practice since:

> A bind call or arrow function in a JSX prop will create a brand new function on every single render. This is bad for performance, as it will result in the garbage collector being invoked way more than is necessary.

Better way:

```js
var List = React.createClass({
  handleClick (id) {
    console.log('yaaay the item key was: ', id)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item =>
          <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} onItemClick={this.handleClick} />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

var ListItem = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this._onClick}>
        ...
      </li>
    );
  },
  _onClick() {
    this.props.onItemClick(this.props.item.id);
  }
});
```

Source: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Comment: Fair point :) I would've added it as a comment to the accepted answer though!

Comment: Technically the selected answer is the right answer and your answer would be an improvement.

Comment: `React.createClass` autobinds all functions, which means this answer is creating the same number of functions as doing `.bind` in the accepted answer. Regardless of moving this to a new component, you will have to bind any function used as a callback in order for it to have the correct context when called.

Comment: @RossAllen if you're using es6 classes you can do that with `_onClick = () => { /* ... */ }` instead of `_onClick() { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @redbmk True. I was only refuting the claim that this is a "Better way". This answer encapsulates `item` by creating a new class instance for each iteration of the loop. My answer only creates a new function on each iteration. Both answers are functional, but this one is not objectively "better"; that is misleading. The `item` or `item.id` must be captured by a new scope (a function) or a new class instance. When functions are partially applied to capture a variable, it's not "bad for performance"; it's necessary for the component to work as intended.

Comment: Yeah I like the [bind operator syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator), which would work more the way you're proposing. I'd be curious to see the performance difference though between creating bound functions in render vs on class instantiation for a page full of elements that get re-rendered often (e.g. [the Sierpinski triangle demo](https://github.com/claudiopro/react-fiber-vs-stack-demo))

Comment: @RossAllen btw, not to pester you, but it looks like the docs have changed. They now mention that `In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.` https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing the re-rendering note. They do use my same example in "Passing Arguments to Event Handlers" below. It's worth measuring whether this actually causes performance problems in your app, which is why I am reluctant to label "Class"-ifying every case like this strictly "better": https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Answer (score 22):

Partially apply the function callback by using JavaScript's native [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). This is mentioned in React's "[Communicate Between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)" doc:

```
callbackFn: function(key) {
  // key is "result.id"
  this.props.callbackFn(key);
},
render: function() {
  var results = this.props.results;
  return (
    <div>
      {results.map(function(result) {
        return (
          <ChildComponent type="text" key={result.id}
            changeCallback={this.callbackFn.bind(this, result.id)} />
        );
      }, this)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why can't you access `key` directly in a better way? This feels like a gross workaround...

Comment: Why does this feel like a workaround? You want to keep track of `result.id`, and by binding that value on each iteration you know it will be what you expect when the function is called.

Comment: it felt weird when I used it at first, but after working with React for a few months (my comment was initially left in Nov) it feels totally normal. You are correct.

Comment: Cool good to know it's working out for you. I didn't realize the date on your comment.

Comment: @Breedly I agree, this won't work for DOM events where you need the event parameter - did you find a way?

Comment: @DominicTobias It will still work for DOM events. The event will be the second parameter. `bind` returns a partially applied function that can be called with additional arguments. `callbackFn(id, event)` could be its signature.

Comment: @ssorallen damn I didn't realise bind did that - good to know!

Answer (score 1):

### We can access data with [Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

```js
// ChildComponent.js
render: function() {
  var results = this.props.results;
  return (
    <div className="something">
       <input 
          type="text" 
          onChange={this.props.changeCallback} 
          data-key={this.props.key} // "key" was passed as props to <ChildComponent .../>
       />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now; in your `changeCallback` method; you can access this `data`:

```js
// ParentComponent.js
(evt) => {
  console.log(evt.target.dataset.key);
}
```

Good Luck...